# How to correctly display an emacs-edited file in atom?

Tags: typescript, emacs, atom-editor, indentation

The project in question is written in Typescript, but I don't think it matters. Emacs seems to have a strange indentation philosophy, in the documentation it says "*In Text mode and related major modes, TAB normally inserts some combination of space and tab characters to advance point to the next tab stop*" ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html))

When I change the tab size from 2 to 8, the like file looks good, but any further editing get totally messed. Emacs seems to separate indentation from tab size, while atom considers them to be the same (I think?). Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I would prefer to have Atom somehow behave like emacs, since that is still my most-used editor.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs will indent to a given *column* and, if `indent-tabs-mode` is enabled, may use both tabs and spaces to get to that column, in accordance with the configured `tab-width`.  So if tabs are allowed, and the tab width is 4, and you are indenting to column 10, it will use two tabs and two spaces.

It *sounds* like in Atom, changing the tab width doesn't alter the number of tabs that Atom believes are needed for indentation.  I *suspect* that means it simply indents by a certain number of tabs, rather than indenting to a column.

My suggestion is that you stop using tabs for indentation.  It can be fiddly in Emacs, and it sounds like Atom may have an approach which is too simplistic to be compatible.  With `indent-tabs-mode` set to nil, Emacs will indent with spaces only, and both editors should be happy.  See also `M-x untabify`.

Comment: Just to spell this out, standard tab width is eight spaces, and you will only confuse yourself and/or others if you change that.

Comment: I agree that this would work, but it requires changing indentation everywhere which is less than desirable for version control. For now, I've decided to stick with emacs until I find a package for atom which lets me configure indentation and tabs separately.